# Viewing Custom Text in Xcode Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard

I have my custom fonts working fine when they are running on the simulator, but is there any way to view custom fonts in the storyboard itself while I'm working? My text doesn't match the size of the default font so I have to keep compiling and running the code and eyeing the correct size by trial and error over and over.

I've seen a few questions hit on this, but it's just bringing up how to upload custom fonts.

Comment: How are you configuring the font? In code or in the inspectors in Interface Builder?

Comment: I imported it and did it in code.

Comment: https://twitter.com/0xced/status/363051175803109376

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in Xcode 4, as it limits you to the preloaded fonts. Xcode 3 had the opposite problem (with .xib files anyway) of allowing you to use any font on your Mac, even if it would not be available to your app at runtime.

Hopefully a future version of Xcode will hit the useful middle ground of giving you exactly what it can determine will be available at runtime. This is actually difficult for Apple to do because the storyboards/nibs live in a project (which may have multiple targets) and the fonts exist in the targets. IMO they should let you use any font and add a build-time warning if a storyboard/nib is built into a target that does not have all the required fonts in it.

What *may* work is to edit the storyboard as text (available by right-clicking) and rewrite the font names in there to your custom font names. If it follows the pattern of other Apple products you will then see the custom fonts but it will "correct" them back to "legal" fonts if you access that element in the inspector. I haven't tried this.

My pragmatic technique is to find a system font which has roughly the same characteristics in terms of character dimensions and leading, and use that in the storyboard for layout purposes.