# Custom font displaying on iOS Simulator but not on Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, fonts

"I have my custom fonts working fine when they are running on the simulator, but is there any way to view custom fonts in the storyboard itself while I'm working? My text doesn't match the size of the default font so I have to keep compiling and running the code and eyeing the correct size by trial and error over and over.

I've seen a few questions hit on this, but it's just bringing up how to upload custom fonts."

I have copied paste this question from [Viewing Custom Text in Xcode Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003374/viewing-custom-text-in-xcode-storyboard) since it describes exactly what I am having trouble with but he had XCode 4 and I have the 5th version. Is there any solution for the XCode 5?

Comment: Oh, I added the custom font programatically and not with the inspectors in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a well established bug. Custom fonts do not appear correctly in Interface Builder. You should file an enhancement request with Apple. Until they fix it, you'll just have to live with it.